# File uploading with python http

Tags: python, file-upload, urllib2

I need to connect to an api to upload a single file (no chunk-usage). All data has to be sent as POST-HTTP-data.... As response I get an link with the uploaded file. The api says fn value is the filedata? filename? I think there is something wrong with handeling the file, cause its gets me an error: `urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 415: Unsupported Media Type`

```
import urllib2
import urllib

query_args = {'username':'admin','password':'123456','upload_session':'ABCDEFGH','chunk_no':'1','chunk_number':'1','finalize':'1','filesize':'104857600','fn':open('test.rar', 'rb')}
url = "http://bla.com/upload.php"
data = urllib.urlencode(query_args)
request = urllib2.request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
```

Comment: if its python why do you need php tag? :D

Comment: the api is php, but my script should be in python

Answer (score 0):

`query_args['fn']` contains a file pointer, not the contents of the file, you need to actually read the file. You probably want to use `open('test.rar', 'rb').read()`.

You also set a fixed filesize to `104857600`; you probably want to get this with `os.stat`, ie. `os.stat(filename).st_size`

HTTP error code 415 means:

> The request entity has a media type which
>   the server or resource does not support. For example, the client
>   uploads an image as image/svg+xml, but the server requires that images
>   use a different format.

Are you sure that `.rar` files are supported? You could try adding a MIME type: `Content-Type: application/x-rar-compressed`

I can't be sure if this solves your problem, since you didn't provide enough details to reproduce it.

Comment: Just for testing i fixed the query_args... Still the error i get urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 415: Unsupported Media Type, after change fn to open('test.rar', 'rb').read()

Comment: @armin884 Try adding a MIMEtype & make sure that rar files are supported.